# Can I trust the Zoom-Snap package?

Tags: security, snap, zoom-meeting

I may be very mistaken, but it seems in ubuntu, the store and the snap store have become increasingly integrated. I've always trusted those packages curated by ubuntu - should I see snaps in the same light? For instance, I was considering downloading Zoom (I have previously used in the browser one) for an upcoming meeting, but I noticed it was both propitiatory and a snap rather than just in the repos. Should such apps be seen as safe in virtue of appearing in the store, or should I judge on a company by company basis?

Sorry if this is a somewhat basic security question.

Comment: As per my experience Zoom snap Package is just safe , I am using it from past 2 years without any issue
It is working really good without any security issue

Comment: The author (Oliver Grawert) is an Ubuntu employee - so this should be in favor of trusting the package.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply, my question was indeed answered by the link provided!

Answer (score 2):

It is proprietary software and should be trusted on a company by company basis or not at all, depending on how you stand to proprietary software. Whether it is packaged as a snap or not, does not increase or reduce its reliability.

Answer (score 0):

I also read a lot about the whole snap thing, as most of the people complain about it. Sometines I understand what they wanna say, sometimes not. I wouldn't see a point against the snap package. According to such type of discussion (snap is good/bad...), I stumbled up on a clip on youtube, where Alan Pope from canonical was ask somethig about that. It was quite interesting to see. It's not according the zoom snap, but snaps in general. So maybe it'll be kmind of an answer for you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8MgktKqjsU

kind regards